# Java 7 NIO.2 Files.getLastModifiedTime time zone

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, nio2

I'm writing a program which needs to determine files/directories last modified time. I want to handle this time using Joda Time, and I'm using Java 7 NIO.2 class `Files` to get file last modified time. Its `getLastModifiedTime()` method returns an instance of `FileTime` class, which has convenient method `toMillis()`, whose result I pass to Joda Time `DateTime` class constructor:

```
new DateTime(Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis());
```

However, I have a feeling that I'm doing this wrong, since `DateTime(long)` constructor explicitly mentions that `DateTime` instance will be created with default time zone. `FileTime` docs, however, do not mention its time zone anywhere. I looked through `FileTime` code; it seems to be very simple, and its `toString()` method suggests that it is using UTC time zone (it creates a `Calendar` in UTC time zone and sets its milliseconds directly).

So, does `FileTime` uses UTC or local time? What is the correct way to convert `FileTime` to `DateTime`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Java millisecond timestamp is a UTC timestamp.  It's what `FileTime.toMillis()` returns, and what the `DateTime` constructor expects.  The same applies to other Java API methods; e.g. the `System.currentTimeMillis()` method, the `java.util.Date` constructor, and so on.

They all work the same way.  And, indeed, so do other Unix / Linux / OSX library methods in other programming languages.

The only case where this breaks is if someone configures / sets the system clock incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. For some reason I thought that `DateTime` constructor expected timestamp in local time zone, but, as you said, timestamp is always in UTC. Then `DateTimeZone` argument in another `DateTime` constructor just defines how this timestamp should be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

FileTime.toMillis() API says  it returns the value in milliseconds, since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). new DateTime(millis) creates a DateTime instance wich holds time in milliseconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z and Chronology in the default time zone which determines how the millisecond value is converted into the date time fields.